# Can't get it! SqlParameter with ParameterName is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection. Stored proc param

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I know that this question has been asked many times,  And I have read many many answers, yet I can't figure out what is wrong.  It's been hours.  Any help would be soo appreciated.  I am just trying to call a stored procedure in an ASP page, and I am unable to add the parameter properly,  getting the exception that it is not in the collection.

I have modified my proc as follows to try to make it simple and isolate the issue.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_validateUserWithClinicCount]     
@HTID       INT = 0,
@ValidUserID    INT OUTPUT,
@MultiClinicFlag    INT OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @vClinicCount   INT = null
DECLARE @vUserValid     INT = null
BEGIN

SET @ValidUserID = 2
SET @MultiClinicFlag = 1
END;
```

AND the C# code

```
String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PC3PaymentConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("up_validateUserWithClinicCount", connection))
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTID", htId);

                SqlParameter uidOut = new SqlParameter("@ValidUserID", SqlDbType.Int);
                uidOut.Size = 4;
                uidOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(uidOut);

                SqlParameter pMultiClinics = new SqlParameter();
                pMultiClinics.ParameterName = "@MultiClinicFlag";
                pMultiClinics.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                pMultiClinics.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pMultiClinics);

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //--> Error points to the next line, and I have tried to use int.parse rather than convert   also, with the same error -- parameter not in collection
                    MultiClinics = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.Parameters["pMultiClinics"].Value);
                    PC3User = Convert.ToInt16(uidOut.Value.ToString());
                }
                catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                {
                    LbMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    LbMsg.Text = sqlEx.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks if you can see what I am missing.

Comment: What id you used @pMultiClinics after the execute instead of cmd.Parameters["pMultiClinics"].Value.

Comment: The parameter is not called `"pMultiClinics"`. It's called `"@MultiClinicFlag"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an object reference for the parameter already, you don't need to grab it from the parameters collection. Also, sql ints are 32-bit.

```
MultiClinics = (int)pMultiClinics.Value;
```

To retrieve from the parameter collection, use the ParameterName you gave it:

```
MultiClinics = (int)cmd.Parameters["@MultiClinicFlag"].Value;
```

Comment: Wow,  Sorry.  I'm very tired and pretty new at this but still pretty silly mistake.  Thanks for your help.  That was it.

Comment: It's int32 in c# and int in the databse.  No problem now